# Issue with Python Turtle

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am toying around with pythons turtle module for the first time (also a beginner with python) and have run into an issue. I am trying to define a class that has a specific method that turns a turtle and then moves it forward. Here is the code:

```
class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        self = turtle.Turtle()
        self.ht()
        self.pu()
        self.color("white")
        self.setpos(0, -270)
        self.speed(3)
        self.st()

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.setheading(180)
        self.fd(10)
```

When I run the program (which created an instance of the player) I get the following error:

"AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute '_orient'"

I'm a little lost so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here seems to be that you are trying to have Player both *subclass* Turtle and *contain* a Turtle.  Usually we do one or the other, but not both.  Here's a solution following on the subclass approach:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__(visible=False)

        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.setposition(0, -270)
        self.speed('slow')
        self.showturtle()

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.setheading(180)
        self.forward(10)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

p = Player()

p.moveLeft()

screen.exitonclick()
```